# Incorrect offset for multiple DateTimeZone in Python using dateutil package but using pytz gets the correct offset value on Windows system

Tags: python, windows, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

```
from dateutil import tz
import datetime
import pytz

now = datetime.datetime.now(tz.UTC)
print(now.astimezone(tz.gettz("America/Mexico_City")))

# output -- 2023-05-16 09:59:43.668933-05:00

now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC"))
print(now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Mexico_City")))

# output -- 2023-05-16 08:59:43.668933-06:00
```

In both cases there is discrepancy in offset value as gettz is showing -5:00 and using pytz it is showing -6:00. This discrepancy can also be found in some other time zones.

In both of these pytz is showing correctly but tz.gettz gives an incorrect offset value. Why is gettz showing an incorrect value am I using incorrectly?

Comment: Hi there and thanks for submitting a question to StackOverflow. I cannot reproduce your issue - both `tz.gettz()` and `pytz.timezone()` work as designed. Which versions of the libraries are you using and which version of Python?

Comment: cannot reproduce this result, I get UTC-6 in both cases. did you make sure all relevant libraries are up-to-date?

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply,  I am using latest versions of pytz  i.e. 2023.3 and python-dateutil i.e. 2.8.2 and python version is 3.8.16. Still i am getting mismatch in time for current utc time.

Comment: on what OS are you running this? is your OS timezone database up-to-date?

Comment: I am using windows 11 edition

Comment: @FObersteiner  Hi os is showing me correct time zone 
(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey
Central Standard Time (Mexico)

Comment: I don't have a Windows 11 installation for testing. Might be a quirk of Win 11. Does it give the correct UTC offset if you use library `zoneinfo` (with `tzdata` installed; on Python < 3.9 you can use [backports.zoneinfo](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/)) ?

Comment: @FObersteiner , yes with zoneinfo in 3.9 i am getting correct offset value. What should i do for gettz? do i need to downgrade my windows or anything else need to do?

Comment: my suggestion would be to use `zoneinfo` via the [backports](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/) in Python 3.8 (if it works) and the standard lib's zoneinfo in Python 3.9. By that, it would be relatively easy to get the code working on both Python versions, without having to rely on the deprecated pytz in one case.

Comment: Hi @FObersteiner, Thanks zoneinfo via backports is working fine and giving correct offsets for 3.8. Going forward if there is any dst/non-dst changes done by any of the states will that be updated in this library?

Comment: Yes, as long as the `tzdata` package is kept up-to-date on Windows. On Linux and Mac this is not necessary since `zoneinfo` can use the OS tz database there.

Comment: @FObersteiner on my local machine i am using windows with python 3.8 and zoneinfo via backports is working fine, but on server we have linux with python version 3.8 and using gettz function. so what will you prefer to use there?

Comment: I never had issues with dateutil on Linux, so as long as you have the latest version of the [IANA tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), you should be fine. You can check the installed tzdata version on your Linux for example on an Ubunutu server via  `apt-cache policy tzdata` or `dpkg -s tzdata | grep Version`. Alternatively, you might use backports.zoneinfo as well. But you should keep your tzdata up-to-date nevertheless ;-)

Comment: Hi @FObersteiner, thank you for helping me in this. On linux when i update tzdata file i am able to get correct offset value. But i am still figuring out why this is not working on windows server even on windows 10 with all the updated packages? Even when i  run tzutil /l on windows machine it is showing me 
(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey
Central Standard Time (Mexico) 
which seems to be updated

Comment: I'm not sure if on Windows this is related to any OS library version, such as tzdata on Linux. AFAIK, neither pytz nor dateutil nor zoneinfo use any OS libraries on Windows to obtain time zone rules. Maybe dateutil has some kind of bug there, but right now, I don't have a Windows 11 or Windows Server version to play around with for testing ;-)

Comment: ok @FObersteiner, I have updated title for this question to check on windows system and could you also pls send this code snippet in your contact to check how it is behaving over windows system? If this issue is coming over windows then we can raise this issue to the python-dateutil community.

Comment: Maybe `-5:00` offset (from `gettz`) is **Daylight saving time (DST)**, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Mexico ? BTW, I hate DST!